# I couldn't save data in DB using Hibernate in WAR

Tags: hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee

When I use a simple class test (HibernateTest.java) .it works well and I can save my object in my mysql Database, but when I use it in a WAR I couldn't save my bean into Database.

this is my HibernateTest.java :

```
package com.live.presentation;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import com.live.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil;
import com.liver.beans.User;
import com.live.business.UserBusiness;
import com.live.business.UserBusinessImp;
import com.live.dao.UserDao;
import com.live.dao.UserDaoMysql;

public class HibernateTest {

    private Session session;


    private void openSession(){
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    }

    private void closeSession(){
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public HibernateTest() {
UserBusiness userBusiness = new UserBusinessImp();
        userBusiness.add(new User("Lee", "lee@gmail.com", "pass00Z"));
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

        new HibernateTest();
    }

}
```

Business layer has UserBusiness interface and UserBusinessImp class.

interface **UserBusiness** :

```
package com.liver.business;

import com.live.beans.User;

public interface UserBusiness {

    public void add(User user);
}
```

class **UserBusinessImp** :

```
package com.live.business;

import com.live.beans.User;
import com.live.dao.UserDao;
import com.live.dao.UserDaoMysql;

public class UserBusinessImp implements UserBusiness{

    public void add(User user) {
        UserDao userDao = new UserDaoMysql();
        userDao.insert(user);
    }

}
```

DAOlayer has UserDao interface and UserDaoMysql class.

interface **UserDao** :

```
package com.liver.dao;

import com.live.beans.User;

public interface UserDao {

    public void insert(User user);
}
```

class **UserDaoMysql**:

```
package com.live.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import com.live.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil;
import com.live.beans.User;

public class UserDaoMysql implements UserDao {

    private Session session;


    private void openSession(){
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    }

    private void closeSession(){
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public void insert(User user) {
        openSession();
        User p = new User(user.getName(), user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());
        session.save(p);
        System.out.println("sauvegarde reussi");
        closeSession();
    }

}
```

Now when I would like to save my data while click on sign up button it doesn't work.

```
    public void save(){

        System.out.println("name :"+name);

        UserBusiness userBusiness = new UserBusinessImp();
        userBusiness.add(new User(name, email,password));

    }

}
```

so when I click on sign up for save data, it throws an exception with below root cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
    at com.live.dao.UserDaoMysql.openSession(UserDaoMysql.java:26)
    at com.live.dao.UserDaoMysql.insert(UserDaoMysql.java:50)
    at com.live.business.UserBusinessImp.add(UserBusinessImp.java:11)
    at com.live.beans.User.save(User.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    ... 37 more
```

I don't understand my problem , and why it's work when I use class hibernateTest and doesn't work in a WAR. Anybody can help me please

**Updated**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>p01</groupId>
  <artifactId>p01</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <name>HibernateTest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
          <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Some libraries are missing in the classpath of your war. If the web server doesn't provide what your app needs, you could add the libraries into its WEB-INF/lib folder...

Comment: But I am using MAVEN please check my post again I will update it for add pom.xml

Comment: There is no easy way to solve your problem from outside. Find which dependency includes the jar that contains the missed class (in this case org.hibernate.cfg...) and set that dependency's scope to compile.

Comment: I would first do a check what jars are actually physically present in the war file's WEB-INF/lib. Probably one hibernate jar that is supposed to be there is not there right now. That might make it a problem of deployment configuration.

Answer (score 0):

check if this jar is included (`hibernate-tools`) in web project, if there try to remove it from build path and put inside `WEB_INF/lib`  then refresh and build

Comment: thanks for your answer , I am using MAVEN please check my post again I will update it for add my pom.xml